# How to animate points, appearing one-by-one, in the window using JavaScript and D3?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, d3.js

Given a set of random points in 2 dimensional space, how could one go about animating the points appearing in the window? Currently the code I have will create all the nodes from the given point set, and then after a short delay all of the nodes will appear at once, not in one-by-one in order. I have found a way using an html canvas and some D3 code, but this may limit my use of D3 as I proceed further into the project.

The end goal is to be able to animate the construction of geometric objects like a t-spanner in the window using D3. I would also like to be able to animate objects like edges, bounding boxes, and more progressively using D3. The reason I chose to use D3 for this project is because I thought the animation process was fairly simple and smooth, I still hope this is the case. Please let me know the best way to animate the construction of a given object. If I can get the nodes animated properly the other objects should be more simple.

Below is the current code, it will animate the nodes but not one-by-one instead all animation happens at once.

```
    function drawVertexSet(s = pointSet) {

    d3.selectAll("g").remove();

    var nodes = svg.append("g");

    for (let i = 0; i < pointSet.length; i++) {

        var circles = nodes.append("circle")
            .attr("cx", pointSet[i][0])
            .attr("cy", pointSet[i][1])
            .attr("r", 3)
            .style("fill", "white")
    }
    
    for (let i = 0; i < pointSet.length; i++) {
        
        vertex = document.getElementsByTagName("circle")[i].id = "vertex_" + i;

        setTimeout(() => {
            d3.select("#vertex_" + i)
                .transition()
                .delay(200)
                .duration(1)
                .style("fill", "black");
        }, 200);
    }
}
```

Comment: D3 follow the [enter, update, exit](https://www.d3indepth.com/enterexit/) pattern. You should try to follow this pattern when using D3

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve the problem. While this patter may be better practice, all the nodes are still animated at once not one at a time. I want the nodes to appear one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <button id="replay">Replay</button>
    <div id="chart"></div>

    <script>
      // set up

      const margin = { top: 5, bottom: 5, left: 5, right: 5 };

      const width = 200 - margin.left - margin.right;
      const height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

      const svg = d3.select('#chart')
        .append('svg')
          .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
          .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

      const g = svg.append('g')
          .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

      // connect button

      d3.select('#replay')
          .on('click', () => drawVertexSet(getRandomData()));

      // random data generator

      function getRandomData() {
        const randX = d3.randomInt(0, width);
        const randY = d3.randomInt(0, height);
        const numPoints = d3.randomInt(10, 30)();

        return d3.range(numPoints).map(() => [randX(), randY()]);
      }

      function drawVertexSet(pointSet) {
        g.selectAll('circle')
          .data(pointSet)
          .join('circle')
            .attr('cx', ([x, y]) => x)
            .attr('cy', ([x, y]) => y)
            .attr('r', 3)
            .attr('fill', 'black')
            // start the circle as invisible
            .attr('opacity', 0)
          .transition()
            // how long it takes each circle to fade in
            .duration(100)
            // how long to wait before transition the circle
            .delay((d, i) => i * 100)
            // make the circle visible
            .attr('opacity', 1);
      }

      drawVertexSet(getRandomData());
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted thank you!